# Got shocked after rewiring my doorbell - how can I safely fix the issue?

Tags: electrical, safety

Stupid question, but I was changing my apartment's doorbell, tried it, closed the door, and went on my way.

**The shock** - 1 hour later, I inadvertently touched the door's handle, I got a small shock - like static electricity can give, so it didn't hurt at all. In fact, it even convinced me to touch it again just to be sure, and small shock again. (Don't do that, it was dangerously stupid.)

**Now** - I may have done something wrong rewiring my doorbell, but I would be surprised if somehow electricity found a way. Door and doorbell are >5cm apart.
It could simply be me being charged with electricity after petting my cat.

Current is off.

- How can I safely check if there's current, and that it comes from the doorbell? I have a multimeter
- Should I wear latex gloves? (keeping the current off, just in case.)

Comment: If you are able to then post a photo of the wiring of the bell.

Comment: Getting a shock from the doorbell is possible with bad wiring.  Getting a shock from the door knob without touching the bell is much harder.  Is the door frame and door metal/steel?  One test would be using a light fixture with a light and two long enough insulated wires.  If light works there is a big problem.

Comment: "Apartment" indicates (to US readers) that you're renting. Doing work like this is often forbidden in a rental. Do you have proper authority to do these kind of repairs? Usually there is a landlord/maintenance staff that are responsible. Even if it's an owned "apartment", the maintenance staff are often responsible for these things to ensure your enthusiasm doesn't end up accidentally killing others.

Comment: If the power is off and you are still getting the shock, it's not from the power. Are you sure power is off to your doorbell transformer?

Comment: @FreeMan - do you mean it is impossible to own an apartment in the US? As distinct from buying into a set of condominiums or a co-op?

Comment: No, no, @MichaelHarvey, but it's far less common in the US (to my knowledge) to call an owned portion of a multi-family dwelling an "apartment". However, my grandparents lived in an apartment in mid-town Manhattan. The building "went co-op" (meaning that the tenants bought it, owning their own apartments), but my grandparents opted out, instead getting to live there rent controlled (meaning minuscule "COLA" to their rent) and they were actually paying a reasonable amount of rent into the 21st century, while their neighbors actually owned their slice of the building.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey   What Freeman meant was that usually only people who own their own single family homes can do electrical work.  The regulations for most multi-family/people buildings(owned or rented) are much more strict.

Comment: You're not using Yankee Units, so it sounds like you might be in Europe/Asia/Africa/Oceania.  Do you have 230V power?  Does your doorbell run on AC mains power as is often the practice in 230V-land?  (here in 120V country we use a 16- or 24-volt transformer to make *even lower* voltage for doorbells and thermostats, because 120V is not low enough LOL).